# Cannot Save Tensorflow_probability model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-probability, bayesian-deep-learning

I'm trying to save the tensorflow model bellow:

```
Model: "sequential_117"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 fcl_0 (DenseFlipout)        (None, 47)                1175      
                                                                 
 BN_0 (BatchNormalization)   (None, 47)                188       
                                                                 
 fcl_1 (DenseFlipout)        (None, 14)                1330      
                                                                 
 final_layer (DenseFlipout)  (None, 1)                 29        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 2,722
Trainable params: 2,628
Non-trainable params: 94
_________________________________________________________________
```

But I'm facing this error : TypeError: cannot pickle 'module' object

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14328/3501717249.py in <module>
      1 # save model
----> 2 best_model.save("model_BNN")
      

[...]

~\Anaconda3\lib\copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    159                     reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce_ex__", None)
    160                     if reductor is not None:
--> 161                         rv = reductor(4)
    162                     else:
    163                         reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce__", None)

TypeError: cannot pickle 'module' object
```

Does anyone have an idea about this issue ? Is that a bug of tensorflow probability ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`model.save` in Tensorflow takes only the name of the save object, and not an extension. This is because it saves a bunch of things in a folder with that name.

`best_model.save("model_BNN")` should work for your case if you are trying to save the entire model.

Check the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_the_entire_model). If you want to save only the weights of your trained model, you can use [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#manually_save_weights)

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. You're right about the typo but it seems it's not the issue as it creates a folder "---.json".
I still have the same issue with the right typo.
```TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14328/2917567130.py in <module>
      1 # save to JSON
----> 2 best_model.save("model_BNN")```

Comment: Saving only weights is working but I would rather use the generic fonction to save the entire model.